# XSLT Append to Result Document

Tags: xslt, code-generation, saxon

I have an XSLT script that I use for code generation where I process multiple input XML files, and output the files to Javascript code.  For each xml input file, I output one Javascript file.

So, I would have the following files/transformations occuring:

```
view1.xml -> view1.js
view2.xml -> view2.js
...
```

Now I have a requirement to also create a one additional file during the XSL processing where I will need to append information regarding each input file processed to a common Javascript file.

So, now I would have:

```
view1.xml -> view1.js / append to common.js 
view2.xml -> view2.js / append to common.js
...
```

My question is, is it possible to append to a file during the processing of multiple input files?  I am currently using Saxon 9.1.0.7, and I looked at the xsl:result-document element, but this appears to overwrite any previously written content.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution or the correct configuration of Saxon to enable appending?

Comment: A Saxon specific configuration would be fine if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you can append to an existing (non-XML, even) file from within XSLT.

On the other hand, appending a result to a file is easily done in the environment that runs your transformation. Be it a programming language or a shell, text file concatenation should be a trivial excercise. I suggest you do it there, instead of trying to find some way of bending XSLT to do it.

Comment: Good point. I do need an attribute from each input file processed, but I could easily extract this using a scripting language as well and append this information. Thanks.

Comment: hmm.. I missed, dont try to solve a problem which doesn't exists :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in XSLT "document()". You can use this to process multiple xml input files from a single XSLT and hence a single output, I am not sure if it helps in your case.

some thing like.

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="document('doc1.xml')"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="document('doc2.xml')"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="document('doc3.xml')"/>

 <xsl:template match='nodeX">do something</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match='nodeY">do something else</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I would prefer not to have to specify the input file names. Right now I am processing all files in an input directory, and supplying an output directory for the transformation files.  There will be many more input files created, and I would rather not have to add a document() element for each new input file.

Comment: for that you can write another xml file on the fly (using some other script). containing name of all the files and process it and add document() tags in a loop in XSLT. This is the best i could think of as of now. :-)

Comment: I would hope there would be a more straight forward way, but this does sound like it could work if there are no other options. I'm using Ant for the transformation, so I could just add a script call in the build, and call another transformation. Thanks